# Modified Binary Search Array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search

EDIT: included improved code.

My current logic is incorrect. I want to have a binary search that will find the integer "wantToFind", and if it is not in the array will subtract 1 from wantToFind until it is found.

I have subtracted this from a larger program, that guarantees that the 1st item in the array will be the lowest wantToFind (the value we want to find) can ever be.

However, despite following binary search conventions the program is still getting stuck when looking for higher numbers such as 88.

```
float list[15] = {60,62,64,65,67,69,71,72,74,76,77,79,81,83,84};

// binary search
int wantToFind = 88; //other tests are 65, 61, 55
bool itemFound = false;

int current = 0;
int low = 0;
int high = 14;

current = (low+high)/2;
//int previousCurrent = -1;

do {
    do {
        //if 61 < 72
        if (wantToFind < list[current])
        {
            //smaller
            //previousCurrent = current;
            high = current - 1;
            current = (low+high/2);
        }
        else if (wantToFind > list[current])
        {
            //bigger
            //previousCurrent = current;
            low = current + 1;
            current = (low+high/2);
        }
        else{
            if(wantToFind == list[current])
            {
                itemFound = true;
            }
        }

    } while (low >= high);

    if (itemFound == false)
    {
        wantToFind--;
    }
} while (itemFound == false);

printf("\n%d", wantToFind); //which will be a number within the list?
    return 0;
```

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand you correctly - you've taken this piece of code that you found somewhere, and you're asking us to explain to you how it is working? Have you done any sort of research yourself? Reading through the code, debugging it with various input, etc? If yes, then please share it . For example, what parts are you able to understand and what parts are you not able to understand?

Comment: @barakmanos Not quite. I want to have a binary search that will find the integer "wantToFind", and if it is not in the array will subtract 1 from wantToFind until it is found. This code doesn't work currently. Apologies for lack of clarity

Comment: So your code doesn't work correctly... and? You want us to debug it for you and explain why?

Comment: @barakmanos Yes please. I've tried several times and this is the closet I have gotten.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that this is not a 'debug my code for free' service. Please do it yourself, and come back with a **more accurate description** of the problem that you're dealing with (if you still haven't been able to solve it on your own by then). Don't just dump your entire code at our faces.

Comment: You talk about integers, but have `float list[15] = ...` in the first line of your code. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine why you'd want `while (low >= high)`. This will cause the loop to terminate the first time through. I'm pretty sure you want `while (low <= high)`.

Also, when the item isn't found, there are three possibilities:

1. `wantToFind` is smaller than the smallest item in the list.
2. `wantToFind` is larger than the largest item in the list.
3. `wantTofind` would be located somewhere in the list.

In cases 2 and 3, the value of `current` when the inner loop exits will be one more than the index that contains the first item smaller than `wantToFind`.

In case 1 above, `current` will be equal to 0.

The point is that there's no need for the outer loop. When the binary search fails, the value of `current` tells you the insertion point.

Also, you probably want to early-out when the item is found.

Finally, do yourself a favor and turn that `do...while` into a `while` loop. That is:

```
while (!itemFound && low <= high)
```

You'll find that a lot easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

Your exit condition should be `low >= high`. Then you will find the first value, that's either smaller or bigger than the targeted one (or of course the one, you're actually searching). Then you don't need this if-statement any more: `if (current < 0 || current > 14)` but you have to check/adjust the result after the loop.

Comment: So if I changed `itemFound == false` to `low >= high`, and after the do while  tested `if (itemFound == false)` then `wantToFind--;`. And then encase all this in another do while `itemFound == false`? (Will update code above)